# fscanf not breaking fully spliting a file

Tags: c, double, scanf

I'm trying to read a file in a comma separated value format, the program reads the first two data types and fails to read the last. Please can I have some help

Here's what's in the file I'm trying to read:

```
Jane,50,400.60
```

Here's the code:

```
    FILE* fptr;
    char fileContent[1000];

    char name[100];
    int age = 0;
    double bBalance = 0;

    fptr = fopen("NTD.txt", "r");

    if (fptr == NULL)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        while (fscanf(fptr, "%30[^ ,], %d[^ ,], %lf[^ ,]",
                             &name, &age, &bBalance) != NULL)
        {
            printf("---------------- \n");
            printf("NAME: %s \n", name);
            printf("AGE: %d \n", age);
            printf("BANK BALANCE: %lf \n", bBalance);
        }
    }
```

This is what the program is supposed to output:

```
----------------
NAME: Jane
AGE: 50
BANK BALANCE: 400.600000
```

This is what the program actually outputs:

```
----------------
NAME: Jane
AGE: 50
BANK BALANCE: 0.000000
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

If you need anything else please comment below.

Comment: ==> `while (fscanf(fptr, " %99[^ ,],%d,%lf", name, &age, &bBalance) == 3) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: just to add to @pmg 's comment, fscanf returns the number of input items assigned. See `man fscanf`

Comment: fscanf returns the number of successfully converted items or EOF, not a pointer (NULL). Without checking for EOF this is asking for a non-terminating loop when fscanf keeps returning < 3.

Comment: @Jens: `fscanf` returns the number of assignments made (of `EOF`), not the number of converted items. They may differ when `*` causes a conversion without assignment.

Comment: yikesRobo, if the line of input does not match expectations, what should happen?  Your choice of error handling affects the best solution to  read good data.

Answer (score 2):

In `%d[^ ,]`, `%d` matches a decimal numeral, and then `[` seeks a literal `[` character, but there is none in the input, so `fscanf` stops.

You may need to use `fscanf` for only one decimal numeral at a time and write additional code to check the characters in between them.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Thanks, removed. Any ideas for a fix in a single `scanf`, or do we have to write more code?